# Twitter Bootstrap nav individual menu item colors

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap with Wordpress.
My navbar items outputting fine, but I want each individual menu item to be a different color. Bootstrap assumes all menu items will have same initial, active and hover color.
I want my ACTIVE menu colors to be different.  Is this possible?

I have tried to target the current_page_item in my css but does not seem to overwrte the defaul twitter .navbar-inverse .nav .active > a, definition. Any ideas? Code below...

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="navbar-inner">
    <li id="menu-item-73" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-73"><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-85" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-52 current_page_item active menu-item-85"><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-70" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-73"><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a></li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could target each individual `<li>` by using the assigned id:

```
#menu-item-73 > a,
#menu-item-73.active > a {
    background: red;
}
```

However, if your page/post changes id, the above css selector would have no effect.

Check out the [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/PME7a/).

Comment: That is perfect as the id's do not change. Didn't know I could target by the LI so directly. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar .navbar-inner > .active > a,
.navbar .navbar-inner > .active > a:hover,
.navbar .navbar-inner > .active > a:focus {
   // your style
}
```

or in less file:

```
.navbar .navbar-inner > .active {
   > a, > a:hover, > a:focus {
      // your style
   }
}
```

Update
try `@navbarBackgroundHighlight` in `variables.less`
I'm using bootstrap, and before i start new project, i change in few files `@import "variables.less";` to new variables file, where I change all variables. Next I creat new folder, where I have my `viariables.less`, `styles.less`, and in `styles.less` i include 3 files:

```
/*
Theme Name: name
Theme URI: http://www.domain.co.uk/
Description: Template for your website.
Author: me
Author URI: http://www.domain.co.uk/
Version: 1.0

General comments (optional).
*/
@import "variables.less";
@import "../../_scripts/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less";
@import "../../_scripts/bootstrap/less/responsive.less";

// your own css code
.header { .. }
```

And I compile only `style.less` which give me `style.css` file.

Comment: that si the style I am trying to override. Is it possible to override this?